# Asymptote Family tree with marriage ties

Tags: asymptote

How can I create a family tree with marriage ties with Asymptote?
Currently, I have this Asymptote program:

```
import drawtree;

treeLevelStep = 2cm;

TreeNode root = makeNode( "Root" );
TreeNode child1 = makeNode( root, "Child\_1" );
TreeNode child2 = makeNode( root, "Child\_2" );

TreeNode gchild1 = makeNode( child1, "Grandchild\_1" );
TreeNode gchild2 = makeNode( child1, "Grandchild\_2" );

TreeNode gchild3 = makeNode( child1, "Grandchild\_3" );
TreeNode gchild4 = makeNode( child1, "Grandchild\_4" );
```

It creates a output like this:
[image: Output]

This is the output that I want:
[image: Desired output]
Thanks!

Second question, how can I change the color of the text(text only) for one TreeNode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: May I have clarification on what should be added?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE; feel free to ignore the Community Bot in this case. That said, it is not clear to me that the Asymptote `drawtree` module is the best choice (or even is up to the task) here. Part of the problem is that a genealogy/family tree is not a "tree" in the mathematical/computer-science sense. If you are open to non-asymptote solutions, TikZ as a [genealogytree](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree) package.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you!
I may consider TikZ.....
Are there Asymptote alternatives to drawtree that are more capable?

Comment: You can certainly do this by hand in Asymptote. Or you can write some code to automate the layout the genealogy tree yourself. Certainly I don't see any pre-packaged solutions available as part of the base distribution of modules in Asymptote.

Comment: Ok! Thank you @WillieWong I think I may write the code for it....